# How can I save multiple files with python?

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api, imagegrab

I'm developing a bot for telegram that keeps open, the first time it saves the file it works normally, but the second time it overwrites the previously written file.

```
filename = str(uuid.uuid4())

def get_print(imagem):
    imagem = ImageGrab.grab()
    imagem.save(filename + ".png", 'png')
    return imagem

@bot.message_handler(func=get_print,commands = ['print'])
def print(imagem):
    time.sleep(1)
    bot.reply_to(imagem, "Baixe o print /down")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['down'])
def down(mensagem):
    bot.send_photo(mensagem.chat.id, photo=open(filename + ".png", 'rb',), caption = filename)
```

Comment: If you want to save multiple files, change the filename each time you save.

Comment: Move the `filename` assignment into the `get_print()` function.

Comment: thanks a lot bro, I did just that and changed it to send the most recent file from the folder, so it always forwards the last print generated

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the filename, you set it once and then each time you call get_print it uses the same filename. You need to edit it in your script somewhere for each new image.